# software rendering with opencl onto opengl 2d view

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, opencl, glfw

I want to build a little software rendering library, because I like the idea of voxels, and the possible other alternative methods of rendering.  Call me naive.

Using vanilla c++, with codeblocks, on a win7 system but with cross-platform intent.  Using glfw for window management.

My plan is to use the gpgpu for opencl (parallel) calcs, then using OpenGL (in 2D view) for cross-platform context management and frame display.

Thus using the gpgpu for accelerated calcs, but leaving it up to me to define what those calcs are for.  And asking OpenGL to just draw my results on screen.

Is there any easier cross platform way of putting my own renderings to screen?

Is this proposed method awesome, or not?

Answer (score 1):

glfw3, which is under development has access to native opengl contexts. you can use that to create an interop opengl context. I haven't tried it yet myself though.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any easier way?
Maybe, but none that I'm aware of.

OpenCL supports OpenGL interop, which makes what you're trying to do very fast.
(i've used it myself, and it was fast, but maybe not as fast as I would have liked, but I used it in a inefficient way)

Is this awesome? Maybe, but remember that opencl can't use all the hardware that opengl can, so if possible, use opengl for graphics.